# Detectar si la pagina esta abierta en otras pestañas con js

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, web

Tengo una duda quiero saber como puedo detectar con js cuando han duplicado la pestaña de mi app web, así como web whatsapp te dice que esta abierto en otra pestaña como se hace con js

Gracias

Comment: Manten una cookie y trata de leerla al inicio cuando cargue, si existe habra otra pagina abierta.

Comment: Como dice @Ricardo, usar una *cookie* o incluso el `sessionStorage` es la forma de hacer esto.

Comment: Podrías revisar esta [pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008177/stop-people-having-my-website-loaded-on-multiple-tabs/11008432#11008432)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día, es muy fácil, solo debes etiquetar la ventana para fijar la referencia y luego hacer el `if`

Aquí te coloqué el ejemplo y puedes verificar la detección en el console.log

```
         function openWindow() {
            var ventana = window.open("https://youtube.com/", "MiVentana");
            console.dir(ventana);

            elintervalo = setInterval(checkVentana_name, 200);


            function checkVentana_name() {
                if (ventana.closed == true) {
                    //Si la ventana ha sido cerrada.
                    console.log("La ventana ha sido cerrada");
                } else {
                    //Si la ventana ha sido abierta.
                    console.log("La ventana ha sido abierta");
                }
            }

        }

        openWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una función a `window.onload`  que pregunte si un valor de un input ya esta cargado o no , ese vendría a ser tu estado. Al tener la función de duplicar  casi la misma funcionalidad que los botones de Atrás y Adelante del navegador se parcha esa parte dejando vació el input. A modo de ejemplo dejo visible el input para tu caso seria cambiar al tipo hidden asi `type="hidden"`.

Fuente : [Link de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922776/how-to-realize-when-a-browser-tab-has-been-duplicated)

```js
window.onload = onLoad();
function onLoad()
{
    if ($('#myStateInput').val() === '') // Carga sin no tiene el estado .
        $('#myStateInput').val('cargado'); //se cambia el estado
    else
        alert("Duplicate tab! Do something.");

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() // Parche de los botones Atras o Adelante 
    {
        $('#myStateInput').val(''); // se inicializa de nuevo tu input
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myStateInput" />
```